# What sort of practice or training I lack?

Tags: chord-theory

If I listen to a song in a I IV V progression ( or any other progression) I am not able to identify the chords/ chord progression (I IV V). 
What do I need to do???what sort of practice or training I lack?

I am new to western music. Can someone help me dissect a song for better understanding- relationship between a melody and a harmony.

Comment: New to Western music is half the story. What about the old half? It may give some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep listening to music.

- Try to sing everything you play.
- Play the I IV V progression and then a random note in the scale. Sing it and sing your way back to the root taking care of singing notes in the scale only. You can ask someone to do the same so you can try to identify a note in the scale after listening to the I IV V progression.
- Listen to a melody and try to follow it with your instrument.
- Use ear training apps/methods
- Listen more. MORE! :)

Hope this helps